# Azkaban does not recognize shell variable

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, azkaban

My target is to create a file on a yesterday-date directory on `HDFS` via Azkaban. The `command` in the `*.job` file is as follows:

```
command=sudo -u hdfs hadoop fs -touchz /user/"`date -d '${etl_date} yesterday' "+%F"`"/_SUCCESS
```

The `hadoop fs -touchz` command can run **correctly** in `Linux` but `Azkaban` says it is wrong:

```
touchz: `/user/`date -d '2017-08-11 yesterday' +%F`/_SUCCESS': No such file or directory
```

How to address it? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Check the quotes in command, either escape quotes surrounding +%F as `\"+%F\"` or remove double quotes surrounding entire date -d command

Comment: @Ravi Thanks for your reply, but this doesn't work as expected..

Comment: Any error you got with above would be helpful.

Comment: @Ravi Thanks man, I resolved this problem by using "bash -c": bash -c "hadoop fs -touchz /user/`date -d '${etl_date} yesterday' +%F'`/_SUCCESS"